# Should I ever create an index over a UNIQUE column?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, unique-constraint

In SQLite, given a table like

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    v  STRING  UNIQUE COLLATE NOCASE
)
```

is there any use in adding an explicit index on `v`?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_t_v ON t (v COLLATE NOCASE);
```

Answer (score 1):

For UNIQUE (or PRIMARY KEY other than INTEGER) constraints, SQLite automatically creates an index.

Creating a second index on the same column just wastes space, unless you want to use a different collation, or a multi-column index.

Answer (score -1):

Indexes allow the database application to find data fast, without reading the whole table.They are just used to speed up searches/queries. Unique key is using to uniquely identify a column.You can use indexes over unique key to perform efficiently

Comment: I was under the impression that SQLite (or probably many others) does add a _unique index_ for every column that is marked as unique, so I am afraid I am just manually duplicating work that is already being done for me.